# «Информированное мнение» – это по-русски?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, стилистика

В интернете встречается словосочетание «информированное мнение».
Режет слух.
Информированный человек – понятно.
Субъективное мнение – понятно.
А информированное мнение – какой-то абсурд. Или нет?

Comment: Звучит как 100% бред. Но даже официоз пестрит фразами типа "информированное добровольное согласие"

Comment: да вот мне тоже кажется что это бред) бог с ним с согласием - что там по поводу информированного мнения)

Answer (score 1):

Самый близкий вариант — ***компетентное или авторитетное***  мнение. Информированным может быть человек, но только не мнение.

**КОМПЕТЕНТНЫЙ**, 1. Обладающий основательными знаниями **в какой-л. области**; знающий. Необходимо обратиться к компетентному юристу. 2. **Основанный на осведомлённости**; веский, авторитетный. К-ое мнение.

**МНЕНИЕ**,  1. Суждение, выражающее **оценку кого-, чего-л.,** отношение к кому-, чему-л., взгляд на кого-, что-л.

И вот **мнение по какому-либо вопросу** можно назвать компетентным или авторитетным, если оно высказано знающим, авторитетным, компетентным,  осведомленным именное в этой области человеком.

Человек же может быть эрудированным, информированным и т.д., но не факт, что он будет специалистом **именно в том деле**, которое нас интересует.

С другой стороны, язык развивается, появляются сочетания слов, выражающих новые понятия. Если они будут достаточно частотными, то могут когда-нибудь стать привычными для слуха, **войти в нашу речь.**

Тогда ***информированное мнение*** (пока еще **условное название**) — это не мнение человека,  информированного вообще, а мнение того, кто имеет достаточно сведений именно в нужной нам области, мнение, основанное на специальных знаниях.

Comment: компетентное мнение это мнение заслуживающее доверия . это состояние мнения которое имеет место быть в данный момент  . а вот что такое информированное мнение это загадка)

Comment: Информированное мнение – это мнение человека,  хорошо информированного в данной области. Другими словами, это мнение эксперта по какой-либо теме.  Это новое понятие, используемое пока  небольшой группой людей. Такое развитие языка возможно, причем оно имеет метафорический характер – перенос по смежности с человека на его мнение. Это пока еще ненормированное значение, которое принято незначительной группой сетевого общества, если уж оно встречается в Интернете, как вы говорите. Это значение может закрепиться в языке или остаться за его пределами,  дальнейшая перспектива для него пока неясная.

Answer (score 0):

Никто не будет спорить, что

```
Мнение эрудированного человека - это эрудированное мнение.
```

Аналогично согласие информированного человека это - информированное согласие:

> Федеральный закон от 21.11.2011 N 323-ФЗ (ред. от 02.07.2021) "Об
> основах охраны здоровья граждан в Российской Федерации" (с изм. и
> доп., вступ. в силу с 01.10.2021)

> доп., вступ. в силу с 01.10.2021) Статья 20. Информированное
> добровольное согласие на медицинское вмешательство и на отказ от
> медицинского вмешательства

Ключевой момент в том, что **эрудированный/информированный** здесь не причастия , а прилагательные. Тогда все ок. Иначе 100% бред.

Comment: речь о том насколько это стилистически верно и осмысленно а не о том используют ли это словосочетание . и примеры ваши сюда не подходят ) гуглить я умею)

Comment: Я обосновал стилистику грамматикой. См мои дополнения

Comment: речь не о грамматике а о стилистике  - грамматически правильное может быть стилистически не верным или не сочетаемым по смыслу и логике

Comment: обосновать стилистику грамматикой нельзя - одно от другого не зависит . это как обосновать  химию кулинарией))

Comment: Строго говоря, стилистику нельзя обосновать ничем. Она зависит лишь от вашего восприятия. Но вот грамматическая корректность - это серьезный аргумент в пользу широкого употребления и как следствие постепенной стилизации. Это и называется обосновать стилистику - грамматикой

Comment: все верно - вопрос о стилистике и о логике - грамматика в данном случае вообще не аргумент
грамматически правильного бреда пишут полно и больше) про обоснование стилистики грамматикой - см выше - обоснование химии кулинарией)

Comment: О какой еще логике? Я знаю формальную логику и еще логику рассуждений. Больше никаких других логик я не знаю. Логика рассуждений у меня основывается на грамматических понятиях прилагательного/причастия и на типичном применении их в русском языке. Я показываю, что это типичный случай применения прилагательного для русского языка. Когда признак, выраженный прилагательным, с субъекта переносится на объект. И привожу ряд примеров для пояснения ЛОГИКИ рассуждений.

Comment: к примеру  логика есть математическая а есть житейская а есть логика здравого смысла и общепринятых представлений . еще  обиходное употребление а таке семантика. грамматика тут никаким боком вообще . нет смысла повторять одни и те же аргументы о грамматике )

Answer (score 0):

Такое сочетание лучше не использовать, потому что я, как носитель языка, совершенно не понимаю, что это значит. Можно предположить, что это сочетание обозначает то же, что и сочетание ‟мнение специалиста”, но специалист не просто информирован — он годами трудится, чтобы разобраться в определенной области.
Если бы мы впервые услышали сочетание ‟информированное согласие”, то оно также ничего не значило бы для нас, но оно прижилось в речи, потому что люди отчетливо понимали обозначаемое этим сочетанием при употреблении его в контексте.

Comment: вот я тоже так считаю - что это какой то бред . но в инете не раз попадалось) . информированным может быть разумное существо которое получило информацию и обработало ее своим  разумом после чего оно стало информированным . мнение не является таковым - то есть по смыслу и по  логике  это бред)

Comment: В языке нет такого правила, что все должно вот так сочетаться. Есть ведь сочетание ‟информированное согласие”, как и множество подобных сочетаний, которые мне лень искать для примера. Никто не запрещает вам так сочетать слова, просто они в контексте должны обретать какое-то значение.  Если люди не понимают, что обозначает данное сочетание, или же у некоторых возникает недоумение при виде данного слова, то его не рекомендуется использовать. ‟Информированное мнение” звучит как ‟мнение человека, которому что-то рассказали”, что, как я полагаю, не совсем то, что человек, использующий это, хочет об

Comment: означить.........

Comment: что значит есть сочетание - если его используют люди не чувствующие язык это не значит что оно есть)

Comment: Под ‟есть сочетание в языке” я имею ввиду, что миллионы людей используют его в своей речи. ‟Информированное согласие” — используется миллионами.